# How to add component props to the array when click on that component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

How to add component props to the array when you click on that component?

So, I have mapped components <Card />, and when you click on the <Card /> their {name} should be added to the array or removed from the array.

But `peopleArr` stays empty.

```
// App.tsx

import React from 'react';
import { useState } from "react";
import Card from "./Card";
import people from "../../data/people";

let arr: string[] = [];

function App() {
const [peopleArr, setNames] = useState(arr);

function addName(name: string) {
  if (name && !peopleArr.includes(name)) {
    setNames((peopleArr) => [...peopleArr, name]);
} else {
    peopleArr.filter((el: string) => el !== name);
}
}

return (
 <div>
  {people.map((person) => (
    <Card key={person.id} name={person.name} onClick={() => addName(person.name)} />))}
 </div>
);
}
```

I tried this and this didn't work out at all

```
<Card key={person.id} name={person.name} onClick={() => addName(person.name)} />))}
```

And I tried to add all that things inside <Card /> component and it didn't work out either, also it saved only one name.

Comment: `peopleArr.filter` is not mutating `peopleArr`. You have to use `setNames` to update its value, like so: `setNames(peopleArr.filter(item => item !== name))`

Comment: @AlexandreNicolas ty, I changed my code, but it's still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is in function calling,your function name is `addName` but you are calling it `addCard`

Comment: Try this:


    <Card key={person.id} name={person.name} onClick={() => addName(person.name)} />))}

Comment: Sorry, it was the typo, I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I had to add in  component itself the `props.OnClick`

```
export default function Card({
    key,
    name,
    onClick,
}: {
    key: string;
    name: string;
    onClick: () => void;
}) {
    return (
        <div onClick={onClick}>
        </div>
    );
}
```